# Change directory in python and extract .html filenames through scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I have written a spider that crawls through a folder named fid and extracts the names of all the sub-folders as a link. Now the problem is that each of these sub-folders have an html page inside them and i want to extract the names of all these html files and add to the current "start_urls", so that i can scrape out required information from all these html pages. I have tried:

```
os.listdir()
glob.glob()
```

but none of these worked. Please help me with this.

Comment: Could you provide some code as a starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One stdlib approach is using `os.walk` in combination with `fnmatch`:

```
import fnmatch
import os

start_urls = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/start/dir/'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.html'):
        start_urls.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```